# Is Miller correct when he says that Daniel in Dan 8:17 feared not due to Gabriel but by the presence of the one having the appearence of a man?

Tags: hebrew-bible, angels, theophany, biblical-theology

Daniel 8:15-17

> When I, Daniel, had seen the vision, I sought to understand it. And
> behold, there stood before me one having the appearance of a man. 16
> And I heard a man's voice between the banks of the Ulai, and it
> called, “Gabriel, make this man understand the vision.” 17 So he came
> near where I stood. And when he came, (AW)I was frightened and fell on
> my face. But he said to me, “Understand, O son of man, that the vision
> is for the time of the end.” ESV

Miller interprets the one having the appearence of man as God himself, the same one who speaks betwen the banks of Ulai. Hence due to Daniel in 7:16 and 9:21ff not being afraid of angels, not even being afraid of Gabriel, Miller concludes that Daniel was afraid because of the presence of God and not because of Gabriel.[1]

What do you think?

Footnotes.

1. Miller, S. R. (2003). Daniel (Vol. 18, Ser. The New American Commentary). Broadman & Holman. Para 1.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest editing your headline question to something clearer such as  "Did Daniel fear because of Gabriel or due to the presence of the one having the appearance of a man? (Dan. 8.17)" If you have not done so yet, please also go to the Tour and Help pages (below, left) for an orientation to the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Miller's interpretation is very unlikely for several reasons.  The OP's question can be stated more succinctly as follows:

In Dan 8:17, what is the antecedent of the implied pronoun "he" - was it (a) Gabriel, or, (b) the one commanding Gabriel to "make this man understand", presumably, God?

To answer this I suggest it is Gabriel for the following reasons:

1. Angels can engender fear in humans as occurred a number of times, especially notice Luke 1:13, 30, 2:9, 10, Matt 28:5, etc.  Note that in Luke 1:13, etc, it is the same Angel Gabriel that frightens people to whom he appeared.
2. Daniel never "sees" the voice commanding Gabriel; that is why he only hears the voice (V16)
3. "Gabriel" is a name meaning "man of God".  Thus, when Daniel reports seeing a "man" (Dan 8:15), this is "Gabriel", the man of God.
4. The matter is further put beyond doubt by the fact that Daniel subsequently in Dan 9:21, says it is the same Gabriel that he had seen.
5. We also know that "no man has ever seen God" according to John 1:18, 5:37, 6:46, 1 John 4:12, 1 Tim 1:17, 6:16, Col 1:15, Ex 33:30, Isa 45:15.
6. Grammatically, the closest (and so the most likely) antecedent of the implied "he" in V17 is "Gabriel" in V16.
7. It was Gabriel that was instructed to explain to Daniel and this is why "he" came near to Daniel

Thus, it was Gabriel that came near to Daniel and made him afraid.

Comment: Brillian, thanks.

Comment: @Dottard Well-answered. upvote.

Comment: + 1 I agree it was Gabriel but a third possibility is the Angel of the Lord rather than God Himself.